# Can't finish "client = speech.SpeechClient()" in Google Cloud Speech

Tags: python, ubuntu, google-cloud-speech

thanks for helping me!

I just set up ***google cloud speech*** and tried to run the code in "Make an audio transcription request" in this website: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-python

the code is shown below after I open ubuntu terminal:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/luffy/env/Lu and-xxxxxxxxxxxx.json"

python

import io

import os

from google.cloud import speech

from google.cloud.speech import enums

from google.cloud.speech import types

client = speech.SpeechClient()
```

However, when I run "client = speech.SpeechClient()" in ***Ubuntu 18.04 terminal in python***, the error happens like below:

***PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/luffy/env/Lu and-xxxxxxxxxxx.json'***

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: I have been able to execute this code with a json key created from a service account which has `Project Editor` role. What permission do your service account (which **Lu and-xxxxxxxxxxx.json** are created from) has?

Comment: Thank you! I open Google cloud platform-IAM and management- IAM, and saw my rold is the owner. I think it's more powerful then viewer and editor.

Comment: By searching a little bit about the error, I think you are having an operational error. Could you have a look that the user who ran python commands has read permission to json file?

Comment: Yes, after I enter `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/luffy/env/Lu and-xxxxxxxxxxxx.json"` , I then used `echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, it shows`/home/luffy/env/Lu and-xxxxxxxxxxx.jso`, proving that I have read it

Comment: But when I install anaconda3 on my ubuntu, it did requires me to add another user. Maybe I should try that user

Comment: I have four users, the default user when I open ubuntu 18.04 terminal is `luffy@LAPTOP-L3BDTS6K:~$`. However, in the beginning I used ubuntu 16.04, and it has user `luffy`,and `root`. I used 16 to download anaconda(including python). But ubuntu 16 doesn't work because I move it from C to D hard disk, then move it back, and it's broken. So I then use ubuntu 18 default user to download anaconda again, and then download google cloud speech. I am really confused by all these users. I have a user called `luffy` too in 18, but I never use it when I download google cloud speech

Comment: I will say that the easiest way to see this is try `nano` this file with all four users (or try to open the file) to confirm which user has access error. Another solution is to move this file to a common accessible folder and change the permission to `744` with `chmod` to make it common accessible.

Comment: Thank you!!! When I used `chmod 744 default user`, `the client = speech.SpeechClient()` works !!!

Comment: Now I'm trying the next code on [Quickstart: Using Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries), which is `file_name = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    'resources',
    'audio.raw')`, but it says `NameError: name '__file__' is not defined`. I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: I've searched for many answers about such an error but no one seems to fix my problem..

Comment: It is better to open a new question and provide details about it (with code and link in the right format) since it is another question and there are too many comments in this question which may lose the answer's visibility. You can ping the question here once created

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is an operational error in the file permissions. One can solve it by giving right permissions to the file by using `chmod` and set right permissions (in this case it is enough with `744` since it will allow all the user to read the credential `json` file).